# Custom local URL results in redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-ads-api, google-oauth

I am using a custom local URL for development of a project that authenticates with both Google and Adwords using OAuth2.

The entry in my /etc/hosts file looks like:

`127.0.0.1    sub.example.dev:3001`

In the Google Cloud Platform console I have an OAuth 2.0 client ID setup with:

- type: `Web Application`
- Authorized JavaScript origin: `http://sub.example.dev:3001`
- Authorized redirect URIs:

  - `http://sub.example.dev:3001/auth/adwords/callback`
  - `http://sub.example.dev:3001/auth/google/callback`

I authenticate with with both Google and Adwords separately. Previously I was using `localhost:3001` instead of the custom URL which was working for both Google and Adwords. After switching to the custom local URL the Google auth still works, but when I try to authenticate with Adwords I get a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error.

The error page tells me that "The redirect URI in the request, sub.example.dev:3001/auth/adwords/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client." The URI reported here is exactly the same as what I have as an authorized redirect URI (minus the protocol).

Why does this work with Google OAuth, but not Adwords? How can I get a custom local redirect URL to work with Adwords OAuth?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, and there was a hint in the question itself. The redirect URL that I pass during the OAuth flow needs to contain the protocol and I had missed that in my config.

The redirect URL I was passing in the OAuth flow was `sub.example.dev:3001/auth/adwords/callback`

I changed it to `http://sub.example.dev:3001/auth/adwords/callback` and now it works! :D